# Django receiving QueryDict instead of JSON (from jQuery post)

Tags: python, jquery, json, django

I have a Django Rest API on back-end that stores questions and answers. I also have question sessions, it's an array of questions that has to be processed within 1 request.

The problem is, it works well when I send those requests from curl but when I do this via jquery Django receives QueryDict instead of json.

My js:

```
$.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sessions/create/', {
    questions: JSON.stringify(questions)
  })
```

When I log JSON.stringify(questions) I see it's looking like it has to be:

> [{"description":"test5","type":"YESNO","to_close":5,"choices":""},{"description":"test5","type":"YESNO","to_close":5,"choices":""}]

I can even copy and paste it to curl, and it will work:

> curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sessions/create/ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"questions":[{"description":"test4","type":"YESNO","to_close":5,"choices":""},{"description":"test3","type":"YESNO","to_close":5,"choices":""}]}'

But when I do via JS, Django receives it this way:

```
<QueryDict: {'questions': ['[{"description":"test5","type":"YESNO","to_close":5,"choices":""},{"description":"test7","type":"YESNO","to_close":5,"choices":""}]']}>
```

My post method looks like this:

```
def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    """Create a session of questions"""

    question_data = request.data.pop('questions')
    session = QuestionSession.objects.create()

    for question in question_data:
        Question.objects.create(
            description=question['description'],
            question_type=question['type'],
            answers_to_close=question['to_close'],
            question_session=session)

    serializer = QuestionSessionSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
    serializer.is_valid()

    serializer.save()

    return Response({
        'status': 'SUCCESS',
        'message': 'A new session has been created!'
    })
```

What is wrong? Since I can easily do it via curl, I think the problem is in jquery request.

Comment: How are you outputting that? What makes you think there's a problem? Does your view actually work? And are you setting the content-type from your JS, like you do with curl?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm outputting with print(request.data) . My view does work when I do requests via curl and it's getting JSON is it's supposed to

Comment: You didn't answer the main question. **What happens** when you send that data from JS? And did you set the content-type?

Comment: @DanielRoseman well it started working when I rewrote it from $.post to $.ajax

Answer (score 4):

I was having this exact same issue and what has worked for me was adding `, content_type="application/json"` inside my post.

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry! Wasn't trying to be condescending. Edited my original post

Comment: To clarify. I only meant that any question can be misunderstood as not being an answer. I otherwise only read polite things in your post. In my opinion it would have needed to be forcefully and intentionally misread to end up impolite. (But yes, people sometimes do that.... )